# How to get the select the sum of a column JOINing with another table where elementxof table1 = elementx of table2?[special case]

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables named *videos* and *rating*.

The first table

```
videos

uploader           video_id

james              ac0255
james              ue2145
isabell            qw2378
```

The second table:

```
rating

video_id           score

ac0255             4
qw2378             2
ue2145             6
```

I want to store in variable `x` the sum of the score of all the videos uploaded by `james`.
Can anyone suggest an SQL query for it?

Comment: you got 3 correct(same) answers.. go accept any as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
SELECT SUM(rating.score)
FROM videos
INNER JOIN rating
ON videos.uploader = rating.video_id
WHERE videos.uploader = 'james';
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple join will do.

```
SELECT sum(r.score)
FROM videos v
JOIN rating r ON (v.video_id = r.video_id)
WHERE v.uploader = 'james';
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the sum of score for James , you need to use JOINS and SUM function of mysql

```
SELECT SUM(Rating.score)
FROM videos as Videos
INNER JOIN rating AS Rating
ON Videos.uploader = Rating.video_id
WHERE Videos.uploader = 'james';
```